# Bypass default wrapping of ^and $ in ng-pattern

Tags: angularjs, ng-pattern

Im getting my regex from an API, and they often starts with ^ and ends with $ (for example `^-?[0-9]+$`). Just putting the regex as a string to ng-pattern results in a `Lexer Error`, since angular adds the ^ and $ by default on strings.

From [Angular API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

> - If the expression evaluates to a RegExp object, then this is used directly.
> - If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in ^ and $ characters. For instance,
>     "abc" will be converted to new RegExp('^abc$').

Very well then, let's try to convert the regex string into a regex object, I thought. So I tried this:

```
json.data.data[i].validateRegex = new RegExp(json.data.data[i].validateRegex, "g");
```

But it result in another error:

```
Error: ngPattern:noregexp
Expected Regular Expression
Expected {} to be a RegExp but was {}.
```

How can I get my regex to work with ng-pattern? Preferably without removing the ^ and $ from the regex.

Comment: Can you add any fiddle/plnkr? It will be helpful for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the string to an regex object works.

But ng-pattern shouldn't have `{{ }}` in it. Changing it from `ng-pattern="{{ regexObj }}"` to `ng-pattern="regexObj"` did the trick!

Comment: thank you for replying your question. I was having same problem as you.